# Installing XP guest on virtualbox OSX snow leopard host - no function keys

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to install XP as a guest VM and cannot get past the liscense agreement because it requires you press f8 to continue. This key press is not recognised by Virtualbox, rather it is interpreted by OSX as the itunes hotkey. Can this be fixed, am I mising something simple?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Right Ctrl + F8